# clean-mailboxdatabase error : unable to sync mailboxes with DS

Tags: exchange, powershell

Trying to run a script to clean exchange databases.  When i run the clean-mailboxdatabase cmd-let I'm getting the following error:

Exchange is unable to clean the database that you specified...Unable to sync mailboxes with DS.

This is through my network account [elevated privileges in exchange] and with a script that had a SVC account with Exchange Organization Admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about the permissions?
Maybe you can try this one step by step?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960147/en-us

**Cause**

In Exchange Server 2003, the database cleanup agent can be run by any regular Exchange Full Administrator. This behavior is changed in Exchange Server 2007. When you run the clean-mailboxdatabase cmdlet in Exchange Server 2007, you must have Organization Administrator permissions. This is true unless you have granted the account or the group in question the minimum permissions set, as described in the "Resolution" section.

**Resolution**

To resolve this issue, use the Exchange Management Shell to add the minimum permissions set. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open the Exchange Management Shell.
2. At the command prompt, run the following commands

> Add-ADPermission –Identity “Exchange Administrative Group
>   (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)” –User  –AccessRights
>   extendedright –ExtendedRights “Administer information store", "View
>   information store status"
>
> Add-ADPermission –Identity “Exchange Administrative Group
>   (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)” –User  –AccessRights
>   GenericRead

To make these commands work, you must also use the Exchange Management Console (EMC) to make your account or group the Exchange Server administrator on the server. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Start EMC, right-click **Organization Configuration**, and then click **Add Exchange Administrator**.
2. Click **Browse** to select the account or group that you want to add, and then click **OK**.
3. Select the **Exchange Server Administrator role** option, and then click **+Add**.
4. Select the servers on which you want to add permission to the account or group, and then click **OK**
   **5. Click **Add**, and then click** Finish.

*Note To fully administer the Exchange server, manually add the user or group to the built-in local administrator’s group on the server.*

Comment: I'll have to double check with our exchange admin.  Was able to run this last week via his script and a simple cmd-let and now it's throwing errors.   Who knows if someone changed rights to my group or not.